# making all form elements with class "form-control" editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use javascript to make all elements in a given form with the readonly attribute editable on a click of a button.

so for i've only managed to get one input element to change as I was using the getElementById but as it is ID this is unique in HTML eyes.

How do I change this so I it targets all input elements with readonly?

see my code:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" id="edit">Edit</a>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="editable" name="" value="someValue" readonly> 
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="editable" name="" value="someValue2" readonly>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
document.getElementById('edit').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('editable').readOnly = false;
};
```

Comment: Did you add the jQuery tag because you're open to a jQuery solution? BTW, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: definitely open to a solution, I've copied in my current js function as I was showing were I'm currently up to. @j08691

Comment: `id` ***MUST be unique per document.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as how you're open to a jQuery solution you could use:

```
$('#edit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.form-control').removeAttr('readonly')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/n43s4py9/)**

Note that since IDs must be unique I removed them and used the class to select the elements. The `preventDefault` is used to stop the link from being followed.

Comment: Great thanks, this worked! just out of interest can the same function be used when adding a toggle to it?

Comment: What do you mean by "when adding a toggle to it"?

Comment: Sorry, i.e. if the #edit button is clicked can this toggle between readonly and editable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
  $("input.form-control").removeAttr("readonly");
});
```

If you use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain javascript solution:

```
document.getElementById('edit').onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var edits = [];
    edits = document.getElementsByClassName('editable');
    for(var i = 0; i<edits.length; i++){
        edits[i].readOnly = false;   
    }

};
```

**Notice**

You had `id='editable'`, I change it into class, cause you know ID is UNIQUE.

Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rehkq61o/)

Comment: Two problems with this solution. First, it doesn't stop the link from being followed which in this case reloads the page. Second, `readonly` is a binary attribute and it's mere presence makes it take effect, so setting it to false doesn't actually do anything.